# How to write a JsonDependencyReportTask for gradle?

Tags: gradle, dependencies, task

Gradle has a built-in [DependencyReportTask](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/diagnostics/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/tasks/diagnostics/DependencyReportTask.java) which will output the dependencies as an ASCII tree.

I see it has a `setRenderer` method, how can I pass in a custom `JsonRenderer` to it and generate a JSON format of the dependencies?

I also found there is a [HtmlDependencyReportTask](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/diagnostics/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/reporting/dependencies/HtmlDependencyReportTask.java), but still can't get the idea of how to do it

Comment: If you look inside the HtmlDependencyReporter used by HtmlDependencyReportTask, you'll see that it already generates the dependencies as JSON.

Comment: I just created my plugin based on the class you mentioned, thanks!